# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 26

Tags: php

Hello im having an issue with my code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$host="localhost"; 
$username="root"; 
$password="power1"; 
$db_name="members"; 
$tbl_name="users";

$link  = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect. Please contact us");
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB. Please contact us");

$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

$uemail = $_SESSION['$queryString'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$uemail'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

if ($queryString == $row[activationkey]){

   echo "Congratulations! You have succesfully activated you account. You may now login.";

   $sql=("UPDATE users SET activationkey='' AND status='activated' WHERE username=".$row['username']);

   if (!mysql_query($sql))

{

    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

}

    }

        }
?>
```

What do you think the issue is? Thanks

Comment: Notice: The syntax color highlighting screws up even here on SO because of the missing `"`. Learn to love your editor's color coding! :)

Answer (score 3):

You are not closing a quote here:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$uemail;
```

Replace it with:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$uemail'";
```

Comment: Thank that fixed that error but now i am getting: Notice: Undefined index: $queryString in C:\xampp\htdocs\html\activate.php on line 16

Comment: @spencer: Well then have a look at this line. Does `$_SESSION['$queryString'];` seem to be correct? Where are you setting it? You should be able t

Comment: You are using directly `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and not `$_GET` or `$_POST`? Whats the content?

Comment: @spencer: Oops, my bad internet connection somehow cut of my last sentence. I wanted to say: You should be able to debug code yourself. After all, you wrote it, right? In order to write code you have to know the correct syntax. Solving syntax errors or this kind of typo errors is not difficult in 99% of the cases.

Comment: sorry its kinda late where i live and i need to sleep haha goodbye i will fix this in the morning

Comment: I think that on line 16 you have to replace ' with "" like `$uemail = $_SESSION["$queryString"];`

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$uemail;
```

There is a double quote missing

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$uemail'";
```

Remember to escape all your parameters used in your sql statements!

Comment: That is not escaping.... it is just proper SQL syntax (as `email` is likely to be a string).

Comment: @Felix: Good point. I leave it up to the OP to read the manual about escaping or ask additional questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to terminate this line with a quote

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=$uemail;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$uemail."'";
$sql = ("UPDATE users SET activationkey='' AND status='activated' WHERE username='".$row['username']."'");
```

Remember to put single `'` or double `"` quotes at start and end of the val where datatype is varchar